# How to create line over UIButtons in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uicollectionview, uitouch

I have 8 UIButtons. Now I want to create line overs these buttons.

I tried and I am able to draw a line. Please check what I am doing.

**MyDrawingView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyDrawingView : UIView{

CGPoint fromPoint;
CGPoint toPoint;
UIColor* currentColor;



UIImage *backgroundImage;
}

@property CGPoint fromPoint;
@property CGPoint toPoint;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor* currentColor;

@end



MyDrawingView.m

#import "MyDrawingView.h"

@implementation MyDrawingView

@synthesize fromPoint;
@synthesize toPoint;
@synthesize currentColor;



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"office.jpeg"];
}
return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

//CGPoint drawingTargetPoint = CGPointMake(100,0);
//[backgroundImage drawAtPoint:drawingTargetPoint];

CGContextRef    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context,10);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,fromPoint.x , fromPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);


}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
UITouch* touchPoint = [touches anyObject];
fromPoint = [touchPoint locationInView:self];
toPoint = [touchPoint locationInView:self];

[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
toPoint=[touch locationInView:self];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
toPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Now in another class I am using 8 buttons on `viewDidLoad` , please check what I am doing.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

8 UIButtons (8 buttons in one line and 10 pixels gap in X-position after every button)

[self method_Call_drawView];
}




-(void)method_Call_drawView{
v = [[MyDrawingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,350,400,400)]; 
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[v setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view addSubview:v];
}

 .h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class MyDrawingView;
@interface iPad_Level1 : UIViewController{

UIButton *btn1;
UIButton *btn2;
UIButton *btn3;
UIButton *btn4;
UIButton *btn5;
UIButton *btn6;
UIButton *btn7;
UIButton *btn8;
MyDrawingView *v;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)MyDrawingView *v;
@end
```

I am able to create view and draw a line on a view but I am not able to touch `UIButtons` and create a line over it.

My line is increasing and decreasing wherever I click but I want this line on my `UIButton`.

please check what I am trying to do itunes.apple.com/in/app/word-search-puzzles/id609067187?mt=8, check yellow and blue line on the buttons.

Any idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Comment: still not clear what you want exactly..

Comment: it may be easier to use a pre-made image, so draw the button how you want it to look in an image editor. Then set the button to display the image you created. Bit hard to know what you want without seeing an example.

Comment: @smick Thanks sir for your reply but I did not understand.

Comment: @AfreenKhan take an UIImageView with the height of 1px and put it above your UIButton thats it and modify it as per your need.

Comment: Ok I took UiImageview on self.view over the button. means [btn1 addSubview:img1];   , now how to create line over this?

Comment: @AfreenKhan : that imageview it self work as a line for you brother you can set the imageview's background color as per your desired color for that line

Comment: please check what I am trying to do https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/word-search-puzzles/id609067187?mt=8, check yellow and blue line on the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You ca add a 1px height sub view before the button you want.

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1)]; // change the 200 to fit your screen
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:lineView];
```

And for moving this line when user click a button use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.5
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {                 
             CGRect frame = lineView .frame;
             frame.origin.y = 100;   // for move
             frame.size.width = 50; // for re-size
             lineView .frame = frame;
         }
             completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             NSLog(@"Completed");
         }
];
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your reply, may I know how to do this?

Comment: this is a good idea, you can then set the background color to what ever you want.

Comment: ok I am trying. But how line will create? when I touch button 1 and then button 2?

Comment: Do you want to move this line when a button gets clicked?

Comment: No Sir , I dont want to do this, In this code the line will appear without touch the button. I want when I touch the UIButton The line will create only on that button size and the line still appear and when I touch button 2 with that line the line will become increase and so on but only till there where button located. If there are 8 button I I touch btn 1, 2 , , and 4 then line will be only till Button 4. Line will increase button by button.

Comment: please check what I am trying to do https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/word-search-puzzles/id609067187?mt=8, check yellow and blue line on the buttons.

Comment: hmm, usually these kind of apps or games involve cocos2d or some other 2d technic, sorry I am not that expert in this, but if you want this in minimum, you can play with my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <QuartzCore/CAGradientLayer.h>
```

Import this and add **quartzcore framework** in the project

```
-(IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender{
    UIButton *m_btnTemp=((UIButton *)sender);
    m_btnTemp.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    m_btnTemp.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
}
```

When you want to remove the bordercolor set `borderWidth=0;`

Comment: Nothing is happening.

Comment: please check what I am trying to do itunes.apple.com/in/app/word-search-puzzles/id609067187?mt=8, check yellow and blue line on the buttons.

Comment: @AfreenKhan : use this code with your button type as custom button rather then round rect.

Comment: -(void)viewDidLoad{btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 25, 25);        //77, 639, 148, 51.5
    btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    btn1.userInteractionEnabled = YES ;
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];}
-(void)btnTapped:(id)sender{
    UIButton *m_btnTemp=((UIButton *)sender);
    m_btnTemp.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    m_btnTemp.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
}